# How to implement the __sync_fetch_and_sub atomic operation in assembly language based on Linux GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I need to write the implementation of `__sync_fetch_and_sub` atomic operation myself in assembly language based on GCC 3.4 which doesn't have `__sync_fetch_and_sub` builtins. But I know little about assembly.

Can anyone help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

here is the implementation of `__sync_fetch_and_add`

```
inline unsigned int __sync_fetch_and_add(volatile unsigned int* p, unsigned int incr)
{

    unsigned int result;
    __asm__ _volatile_ ("lock; xadd %0, %1" :
            "=r"(result), "=m"(*p):
            "0"(incr), "m"(*p) :
            "memory");
    return result;
}
```

`__sync_fetch_and_add(int *ptr, int a_count)` is to atomically add a_count to the variable pointed by ptr. return the value that had previously in memory.

`__sync_fetch_and_sub(int *ptr, int a_count)` is to atomically subtract a_count from the variable pointed by ptr. return the value that had previously in memory.

Comment: Wouldn't `__sync_fetch_and_add(ptr, -a_count)` do the job?

Comment: I thought this wouldn't work because the second parameter was unsigned  int, so if we pass -a_count then the value passed will not be the one we want. But now I think this also works for this case. Thanks. But I mark the other one as the answer because I want to know how to implement it in assembly language.

Comment: The posted answer is identical to `__sync_fetch_and_add(ptr, -a_count)`, but it duplicates the code from the question instead of calling it.  And BTW, if you don't actually use the return value, the compiler *can* just use `lock; sub` to update the value in memory without putting the old value into a register.

Comment: I think your constraints are buggy.  You should use a `"+m"(*p)` constraint, instead of telling the compiler you can read the input from an input separate from the output!  Or at least use `"1"(*p)` for the input, a matching constraint for the 2nd output, if that works.  You don't use `%3` anywhere in your template; you just assume it's the same memory operand as `%1`.  So you should write constraints to make sure the compiler can't try to use this as a copy-and-add.

Comment: And BTW, the `"memory"` clobber is only needed to implement the `sync` memory barrier part of the semantics.  Without it, you'd have a `memory_order_relaxed` operation, as far as compile-time reordering is concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This snippet uses the atomic version of `xadd`: exchange and add: it atomically add the right operand to the left (here to memory) and returns the initial value in memory in the right operand. The `lock` statement before ensure the atomicity of the operation.

However, gcc uses the AT&T notation, so the left and right arguments in this explanation (taken from the intel manual) are reversed.

As there is no `xsub` instruction on intel architecture, the easiest way to emulate this is first to take the opposite of the number you want to substract and then add/exchange it atomically:

```
inline unsigned int __sync_fetch_and_sub(volatile unsigned int* p,
    unsigned int decr)
{
    unsigned int result;

    __asm__ __volatile__ ("lock; xadd %0, %1"
            :"=r"(result), "=m"(*p)
            :"0"(-decr), "m"(*p)
            :"memory");
    return result;
}
```

<strike>I also remove the `unsigned` properties, I don't find they are relevant in this case.</strike>

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `xadd` is interlocked whether or not you give it a `lock` prefix, right?  Also, why do you need the `"memory"` clobber?

Comment: @tmyklebu The [intel manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) reads "This instruction can be used with a `LOCK` prefix to allow the instruction to be executed atomically". I suppose the normal instruction is divided into multiples micro-ops and can cause non-atomic behavior in a multi-core context (not sure it's the only case though). As for the `memory` thingy I admit I've been lazy and took the OP's code as a starting point. I'll see if you can get rid of it.

Comment: @tmyklebu I looked up the clobber of `memory` and found this [handy doc](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly#Clobbered_Registers_List) from osdev. gcc likes to optimize out inline assembly and it is advised to use `_volatile_` and to clobber `"memory"` when doing something that writes on memory. Not sure if it's really vital here but better be safe than sorry I guess :).

Comment: I'd leave things with `unsigned`. That has a clearly defined semantic for overflow, whereas `signed` is implementation defined. So a user of that code would always have to guess (or to look up if it is documented) what the behavior would be.

Comment: @JensGustedt thanks, I read about it and learned about the depth of this pitfall. I will correct that shortly.

Comment: @lbonn: My point was that the memory clobber is unnecessary since you only write to %1 and you've already explicitly declared that in the output operands.

Comment: Would love to get an ARM variant.